# jsf file not getting loaded from its location

Tags: jsf

Here is my folder structure of my project,

[image]

File contents;
commons.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"> 
   <h:head></h:head>
   <h:body> 
      <div style="border-width:2px; border-color:green; border-style:solid;">
         <ui:insert name="header" >
            <ui:include src="/templates/header.xhtml" />
         </ui:insert> 
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div style="border-width:2px; border-color:black; border-style:solid;">
         <ui:insert name="content" >
            <ui:include src="/templates/contents.xhtml" />
         </ui:insert>    
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div style="border-width:2px; border-color:red; border-style:solid;">
         <ui:insert name="footer" >
            <ui:include src="/templates/footer.xhtml" />
         </ui:insert>
      </div>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

contents.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
   <body>
      <ui:composition> 
         <h1>Default Content</h1>
      </ui:composition> 
   </body>
</html>
```

footer.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
   <body>
      <ui:composition> 
         <h1>Default Footer</h1>
      </ui:composition> 
   </body>
</html>
```

header.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
   <body>
      <ui:composition> 
         <h1>Default Footer</h1>
      </ui:composition> 
   </body>
</html>
```

home.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
   <h:body>
      <ui:composition template="templates/common.xhtml">    
         <ui:define name="content">             
            <br/><br/>
             <h:link value="Page 1" outcome="page1" />
             <h:link value="Page 2" outcome="page2" />          
            <br/><br/>
         </ui:define>
      </ui:composition>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

page1.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
   <h:body> 
      <ui:composition template="templates/common.xhtml">
         <ui:define name="header">
            <h2>Page1 header</h2>
         </ui:define>           
         <ui:define name="content">
            <h2>Page1 content</h2>
             <h:link value="Back To Home" outcome="home" />
         </ui:define> 
         <ui:define name="footer">
            <h2>Page1 Footer</h2>
         </ui:define>           
      </ui:composition> 
   </h:body> 
</html>
```

page2.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
   <h:body> 
      <ui:composition template="templates/common.xhtml">
         <ui:define name="header">
            <h2>Page2 header</h2>
         </ui:define>           
         <ui:define name="content">
            <h2>Page2 content</h2>
             <h:link value="Back To Home" outcome="home" />
         </ui:define> 
         <ui:define name="footer">
            <h2>Page2 Footer</h2>
         </ui:define>           
      </ui:composition> 
   </h:body> 
</html>
```

When I run the server and run the page, I see a blank screen,

I somehow feel the template file is not getting loaded from the correct location but where can I find the exact location the file is trying to load from.

Html code of the file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
   <h:body>
      <ui:composition template="templates/common.xhtml">    
         <ui:define name="content">             
            <br/><br/>
             <h:link value="Page 1" outcome="page1" />
             <h:link value="Page 2" outcome="page2" />          
            <br/><br/>
         </ui:define>
      </ui:composition>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the contents of your faces-config.xml? What is the url you use to open the page?

Comment: Have you been through a basic JSF tutorial? Did you understand every aspect of it, including the how and the why of the `<url-pattern>` of the `FacesServlet`? By the way, all with all, your question contains extremely a lot of noise. Surely exactly the same problem is reproducible with only one or two Facelet files.